# How do I convert from a decimal number to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format?

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754

How would I go about manually changing a decimal (base 10) number into IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format? I understand that there is three parts to it, a sign, an exponent, and a mantissa. I just don't completely understand what the last two parts actually represent.

Comment: these will help http://www.madirish.net/240   and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIrQtuoT5Ak

Comment: you can try this link http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Find the largest power of 2 which is smaller than your number, e.g if you start with x = 10.0 then 2<sup>3</sup> = 8, so the exponent is 3. The exponent is biased by 127 so this means the exponent will be represented as 127 + 3 = 130. The mantissa is then 10.0/8 = 1.25. The 1 is implicit so we just need to represent 0.25, which is 010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 when expressed as a 23 bit unsigned fractional quantity. The sign bit is 0 for positive. So we have:

```
s | exp [130]  | mantissa [(1).25]            |

0 | 100 0001 0 | 010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |

0x41200000
```

You can test the representation with a simple C program, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
    int i;
    float f;
} U;

int main(void)
{
    U u;
    
    u.f = 10.0;
    
    printf("%g = %#x\n", u.f, u.i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a MATLAB script do so so? Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick: if you have a MATLAB problem then please post it as a new question.

Comment: Hi, A 'c' Code would be great as well. Just wanted a reference code to implement your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Drazick: there is C code in the answer above - or do you need something different ?

Comment: I meant a function which its input is a single / double precision number and its output is a string of 32 / 64 bits which are the representation of the input number. Thank you.

Comment: @Drazick: OK - I don't really have the bandwidth to do that just now - try and implement it yourself and then if you get stuck post a new question. Note also there are online calculators which can do this for you, e.g. http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: @Royi: The general case of strtod is highly non-trivial to make a computer do correctly and efficiently.  It potentially requires extended-precision integer to handle an integer or fractional part that's wider than uint64_t.  Actual code would either be wrong for some cases, or too complex to actually help understanding of the basic steps.  See https://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-to-floating-point-needs-arbitrary-precision/ /  https://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/ / https://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/

Answer (score 12):

Take a number 172.625.This number is Base10 format.

Convert this format is in base2 format
For this, first convert 172 in to binary format

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
 1  0  1  0  1 1 0 0
172=10101100
```

Convert 0.625 in to binary format

```
0.625*2=1.250   1
0.250*2=.50     0
0.50*2=1.0      1
0.625=101
```

Binary format of 172.625=10101100.101. This is in base2 format 10101100*2

Shifting this binary number

```
1.0101100*2 **7      Normalized
1.0101100 is mantissa
2 **7 is exponent
```

add exponent 127 7+127=134

convert 134 in to binary format

```
134=10000110
```

The number is positive so sign of the number 0

```
0 |10000110 |01011001010000000000000
```

Explanation:
The high order of bit is the sign of the number.
number is stored in a sign magnitude format.
The exponent is stored in 8 bit field format biased by 127 to the exponent
The digit to the right of the binary point stored in the low order of 23 bit.
NOTE---This format is IEEE 32 bit floating point format

Comment: Shouldn't the mantissa in your IEEE FP Format be 01011000000000000000000?

Answer (score 8):

A floating point number is simply [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Let's say I asked you to express the [circumference of the Earth in meters](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzcircumference.htm), using scientific notation. You would write:

4.007516×10<sup>7</sup>m

The *exponent* is just that: the power of ten here. The mantissa is the actual digits of the number. And the sign, of course, is just positive or negative. So in this case the exponent is 7 and the mantissa is 4.007516 .

The only significant difference between IEEE754 and grade-school scientific notation is that floating point numbers are in *base 2*, so it's not times ten to the power of something, it's times two to the power of something. So where you would write, say, 256 in ordinary human scientific notation as:

2.56×10<sup>2</sup> (mantissa 2.56 and exponent 2),

in IEEE754, it's

1×2<sup>8</sup> — the mantissa is 1 and the exponent is 8.