# How to calculate Binary Equivalent of 21.36 with an error less than (0.01)

Tags: binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert from a decimal number to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404675/how-do-i-convert-from-a-decimal-number-to-ieee-754-single-precision-floating-poi)

How to calculate Binary Equivalent of 21.36 with an error less than (0.01)

i have converted 21 to binary 10101 and 36 to binary 100100  but now how i will proceed , please help some one.

Comment: Voted to reopen, as the IEEE 754 format is not at all the answer to this question.

Comment: The suspected duplicate link which is provided is no way related to my question . if a person have the same question which i have posted here  ,and  visit that reference link , he will no way get any guidance or help from there , so i request to make this question live. 

members who have voted for close , please explain  how i will get my answer from your referred duplicate link and explain the process.

Comment: This question specifically asks for something (meaning of 'fractional binary') which could be answered as part of an answer to the IEEE754 question, but has not been, as of now. I also feel it makes sense to answer this question in a context free of complications such as mantissa, hidden bit, denormal ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fraction part should not be converted as a number itself, but as a fraction. Converting 36 to binary isn't the same as converting 0.36 to binary.

Converting the fraction to binary works the same, but instead of using 1, 2, 4, 8 et.c., you are using 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 et.c.

To represent 0.36:

```
0 times 1/2 (0.5)
1 times 1/4 (0.25), leaves 0.11
0 times 1/8 (0.125)
1 times 1/16 (0.0625), leaves 0.0475
1 times 1/32 (0.03125), leaves 0.01625
1 times 1/64 (0.015625), leaves 0.000625
```

That takes you below 0.01, so the complete bianry representation of a number close enough to 21.36 is:

```
10101.010111
```

The exact value of that number in decimal is 21.359375.

Comment: Stopping at 1/64 works in this case but not in general. If, for some x, powers of 2 down to 1/2**p have been subtracted from x from the ongoing residue, then the current residue might be almost 1/2**p. E.g., for 1/64, the residue might be 1/128+1/256+1/512+…, which can be any number under 1/64. So the residue could exceed .01.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Don't stop at a specific bit, stop when the residue is small enough. There is no point in calculating more zero bits until the potential residue is small enough, when you know the actual residue.

Comment: My point is the answer should explicitly state the stopping criterion. As currently written it does not; the demonstrative pronoun “that” has no explicit antecedent and is unclear. I suggest you edit it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There is only one number in the entire answer that is below 0.01, what is unclear?

Comment: @Guffa 

if we convert .36 to binary it comes like 010110101.... 
but the actual answer is (decimal part) 010111 , but how we can reach to the original answer is not clear ,if you clear this point then it will be very helpful.

Comment: @SoumyaBiswas: Converting 0.36 to binary gets you (first 20 digits) 01011100001010001111. You only need the first six digits (010111) to get you less than 0.01 from 0.36.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Please post your own answer, don't to a total rewrite of the answer that I posted.

Comment: @Guffa: StackOverflow is a wiki.

Comment: It makes no sense to say “The fraction part should not be converted as a number itself”. The fraction part is a number itself; there is no other way to convert it than as a number. This should be corrected by saying instead that the fraction should not be converted in the same way as an integer.

Comment: The answer does not state how the digits are determined, nor does it explain subtracting powers of two to reduce the residue.

Comment: Although “et cetera” is two words, “et.c.” is not used as an abbreviation for it. The most common abbreviation is “etc.”.

Comment: “Binary” is misspelled as “bianry”.

Comment: The answer contains no discussion of rounding, which, for some values, provides a result with less error without using any more digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The fact that you *can* replace an answer completely, doesn't mean that you *should*. Did you really downvote the answer because I didn't let you replace it with your own text?

Comment: @EricPostpischil : it will be also very helpful for others if you post your answer .

Comment: @Guffa: The point is answers are not owned by individuals. They are intended to be edited to improve them. You have no ownership rights in them. Why will you not even fix the spelling errors?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You can make improvements to answers, but you can't replace the entire text. If you want to fix spelling errors you do that, you don't replace the entire answer.