# How do i convert a single-precision floating point number into decimal?

Tags: binary, ieee-754

If this value 0010 0100 1001 0010 0100 1001 0010 0100 is a single precision floating point how do i convert it into decimal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert from a decimal number to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404675/how-do-i-convert-from-a-decimal-number-to-ieee-754-single-precision-floating-poi)

Comment: No, Im trying to convert floating point to decimal ,not decimal to floating point

Comment: Take a look at Example 6 on [this page](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8281/10w/notes/100_ieee754_conversions.txt).

Answer (score 0):

If you know some basic of Python ,May be you can use struct & binascii module to do it! For more see https://pymotw.com/2/struct/index.html#module-struct