# Negative decimal number / string to IEEE Single Precision Format

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I am taking an Assembly Programming class, and having a terrible time understanding "IEEE Single Precision Format."  Our text only has two sentences about this, and the few websites I have seen discuss it, were not overly helpful.  In full disclosure, this is one of the questions on our weekly assignment and I just can't figure it out.  I sort of understand normal numbers, but as soon as the assignment had a negative number, it just threw everything out the window.

"Use IEEE single precision format to encode the decimal number -1.25 in single-precision floating point. Show all your work for credit."

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is quite detailed. Show your effort and where you got stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I convert from a decimal number to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2404675/547981)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert from a decimal number to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404675/how-do-i-convert-from-a-decimal-number-to-ieee-754-single-precision-floating-poi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message suggests negative numbers are giving you trouble. Simply ignore that the number is negative, and convert `1.25` instead. Then flipping the top-bit will give you the result for `-1.25`. Floats are nice this way: To negate, all you need to do is flip the top bit.

Details: Remember that a single-precision number has 32 bits. 1-bit for sign, 8-bit for exponent, and 23-bit for significand. For "normal" numbers, there's an implicit 1, i.e., the value is:

```
 (-1)^s * 1.significand * 2^exponent
```

(The `1` in `1.significand` is the "implicit" 1.)

You need to figure out what needs to go for `s`, `exponent` and `significand` bits for your number; such that the above formula equals the number you want to represent. (More precisely: "closest" to it, since you'll have to round as not all numbers are accurately representable for cardinality reasons.)

Sign bit is easy: We know it'll be `1` since your number is negative.

Then there's 8-bits of exponent. This can be found by finding what power of 2 is "just below" your number. In this case `2^0 = 1 < 1.75 < 2 = 2^1`, so the closest power is 0. IEEE stores exponents with a bias of 127, meaning instead of E, it'll store E+127. (There are good reasons for doing this, easily googleable.) So, the exponent will be 0+127 = 127, or `01111111`.

Then comes the 23 bit significand. For normal numbers, there's an implicit `1`; meaning you need to simply represent `0.25` in 23 bits. Well, that's easy: After the *dot* powers go in negatives starting from one, so `010...0` will do, since `0*2^-1 + 1*2^-2 = 1/4 = 0.25`.

Putting it all together, you end up with: `10111111101000000000000000000000`. Printed prettily, this is:

```
  ENCODED = -1.25 :: Float
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------S23----------
   Binary layout: 1 01111111 01000000000000000000000
      Hex layout: BFA0 0000
       Precision: Single
            Sign: Negative
        Exponent: 0 (Stored: 127, Bias: 127)
  Classification: FP_NORMAL
          Binary: -0b1.01
           Octal: -0o1.2
         Decimal: -1.25
             Hex: -0x1.4
   Rounding mode: RNE: Round nearest ties to even.
            Note: Conversion from "-1.25" was exact. No rounding happened.
```

Comment: Note that the rounding mode isn't a factor here because `-1.25` can be represented exactly.  BTW, what did you use to dump the details of the conversion-result?  https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html is great for humans for messing around with single-precision, but doesn't allow linking specific numbers.

Comment: @PeterCordes I use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/crackNum. It's not too easy to install (requires a Haskell compiler and an SMT solver), but it does a good job of displaying such values in detail. In particular, it can decode using arbitrary exponent+significand bit widths, including half- and brain-floats. – alias 6 mins ago    Delete