# converting a number to a binary code using the IEEE 754 standard 24bits

Tags: ieee-754

I have a question about coverting number with IEEE 754 standart.
But I have 24 bits(1 bit is allocated to the sign / 7 bits are allocated to the exponent / remaining 16 bits are allocated to the mantissa)

Unfortunately I don't know how I can do that.
Maybe someone could help?

Comment: We're missing one or two details here. :-) What programming language? What form does the input take? What form should the output take? Do you have any example inputs and outputs to work with? Should the code handle IEEE 754 corner cases like infinities, NaNs, signed zeros, subnormals? Will the input always be exactly representable in the target format? If not, what rounding rule or rules should be used? Do you have any code already? What part of the the problem are you stuck on?

Comment: i mean it without any programming. Just have some number and convert it using ieee 754

Comment: Thanks - probably worth clarifying that in the question text (important details shouldn't be left to comments). Many of my questions still hold: what's the expected form of the output? A bit string? Round using ties-to-even? Note: there _is_ no IEEE 754 24-bit format, but it's clear what a hypothetical IEEE 754 24-bit binary format would look like - I assume that those are the rules you'd want to follow? (E.g., precision of 25 bits with the topmost bit encoded in the exponent, bias of 63, unbiased exponent of 0 for subnormals and zeros, unbiased exp. of 127 for infs and nans, etc.)?

Comment: Also, there are lots of existing questions along these lines: e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/2404675/270986 (specifically for single precision, but it shouldn't be too hard to adjust for your needs).

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the ordinary IEEE-754 scheme for binary formats:

1. Set the sign: Starting with a number *x*, if *x* is non-negative, set the sign bit to 0. If *x* is negative, or you wish to encode a negative zero, set the sign bit to 1. Set `t` to |*x*| (the absolute value of *x*).
2. Determine the exponent: Set *e*, an exponent counter, to 0. While *t* is less than 1 and *e* is greater than −62, multiply *t* by 2 and add −1 to *e*. While *t* is 2 or greater and *e* is less than 63, multiply *t* by ½ and add +1 to *e*. (At most one of those loops will execute, depending on the starting value of *t*.) (The limits on the represented exponent are −62 and +63, inclusive, so the loops stop if *t* reaches either one.)
3. Round the significand: Multiply *t* by 2<sup>24</sup>. Round it to an integer using the desired method (most often round-to-nearest, ties-to-even-low-bit). If *t* is 2<sup>25</sup> or greater, multiply it by ½ and add +1 to *e*.
4. If *t* is less than 2<sup>24</sup>, *x* is in the subnormal (or zero) range. Set the exponent field to all zeros. Write *t* in binary, with leading 0 bits to make 24 bits total. Set the primary significand field to those bits. Stop.
5. If *e* is greater than 63, *x* does not fit in the finite range. Set the exponent field to all ones and the primary significand field to all zeros. This represents an infinity, with the sign bit indicating +∞ or −∞. Stop.
6. The exponent is encoded by putting *e*+63 in the exponent field, so write *e*+63 in binary, using leading 0 bits as necessary to make 7 bits, and put them into the exponent field. Write *t* in binary. It will be 25 bits. Put the low 24 bits in the primary significand field. Stop.